# Issues when creating and validating AWS ACM certificate using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-acm

I'm trying to create and validate an AWS ACM certificate with Terraform. This is my config:

```
// not used in this config, but it does exist
resource "aws_route53_zone" "main" {
  name = "mycompany.com"
}

resource "aws_route53_zone" "dev" {
  name = "dev.mycompany.com"
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate" "cert" {
  domain_name       = "*.dev.mycompany.com"
  validation_method = "DNS"
  key_algorithm     = "RSA_2048"
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "records" {
  for_each = {
    for dvo in aws_acm_certificate.cert.domain_validation_options : dvo.domain_name => {
      name   = dvo.resource_record_name
      record = dvo.resource_record_value
      type   = dvo.resource_record_type
    }
  }
  allow_overwrite = true
  name            = each.value.name
  records         = [each.value.record]
  ttl             = 300
  type            = each.value.type
  zone_id         = aws_route53_zone.dev.zone_id
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "validation" {
  certificate_arn = aws_acm_certificate.cert.arn
  validation_record_fqdns = [for record in aws_route53_record.records : record.fqdn]
}
```

But `aws_acm_certificate_validation` creation takes forever:

```
aws_acm_certificate_validation.validation: Still creating... [5m30s elapsed]
```

It never ends.

If I stop the execution with `Control + C`, I get this:

> waiting for ACM Certificate ({arn here}) to be issued: context
> canceled

What is wrong in my configuration?

Comment: Do you have `aws_route53_zone.my_zone` defined somewhere in your code?

Comment: Yes, I do, but I didn't included it in the example.

Comment: I have included zones info. I found it important to include that I have those two zones.

Comment: Can you try using `domain_name = "*.${aws_route53_zone.dev.name}"` in the ACM certificate resource?

Comment: I just tried. Same happens.

Comment: What about leaving the `domain_name = aws_route53_zone.dev.name` and then using `subject_alternative_names = ["*.${aws_route53_zone.dev.name}"]`?

Comment: Same happens...

Comment: Do you have a domain registered for your company at all in Route53?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: You should use some sort of DNS lookup tool to verify that the DNS records being created by Terraform for the ACM validation are actually resolvable on the Internet. If not, then you have something wrong with your DNS configuration outside of Terraform.

Comment: Last time I checked ACM did not support wildcards, you need to specified each subdomain and domain as alternative names and validate each. Check ```https://renehernandez.io/snippets/terraform-and-aws-wildcard-certificates-validation/```

Comment: @victorm As Marko suggested, I tried also with alternative names and it didn't work either.

Comment: change the domain name to "dev.mycompany.com" and add   "*.dev.mycompany.com" to the alternative names.

Comment: I already did that. It doesn't work. Is it possible the validation to take more than 30 minutes?

Comment: It should not take 30 minutes. Have you check Cloudtrail, to see if a permission is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Problem was due a hosted zone misconfiguration (I changed NS records manually and they didn't match with SOA record). Nothing related to the certificate itself; code in the question is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the DNS propagation delay that's getting you. It might take up to 72 hours.

Also, did you try creating via Console? Does it work?